# Solving Schrodinger equation with a harmonic oscillator potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, schroedinger-equation, harmonic-oscillator

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is referenced from the textbook Introduction to Quantum Mechanics by Griffith. I am learning about the application of ladder operators to solve algebraically the Shrodinger equation for harmonic oscillators, but have a problem figuring out how to obtain equation 2.66 for quite some time. Can someone point out how can this be obtained?

Comment: As a side note: Griffith is one of very few (possibly the only?) authors to use $a_\pm$ rather than $\hat a$ and $\hat a^\dagger$.

Comment: I see, thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining Eq. (2.58) and (2.62) gives

\begin{equation*}
\hbar \omega \left( a_{\pm } a_{\mp } \pm \frac{1}{2}\right) \psi _{n} =\hbar \omega \left( n+\frac{1}{2}\right) \psi _{n}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\left( a_{\pm } a_{\mp } \pm \frac{1}{2}\right) \psi _{n} =\left( n+\frac{1}{2}\right) \psi _{n} .
\end{equation*}

This is two equations in one, one of which is

\begin{equation*}
\left( a_{+} a_{-} +\frac{1}{2}\right) \psi _{n} =\left( n+\frac{1}{2}\right) \psi _{n}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\rightarrow a_{+} a_{-} \psi _{n} =n\psi _{n} .
\end{equation*}

The other one is

\begin{equation*}
\left( a_{-} a_{+} -\frac{1}{2}\right) \psi _{n} =\left( n+\frac{1}{2}\right) \psi _{n}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\rightarrow a_{-} a_{+} \psi _{n} =( n+1) \psi _{n} .
\end{equation*}

Comment: Oh I see... I realised how dumb I am to not reading the equation properly. Thanks so much for the help as I have been beating around the bush for so long.